# HTC Blinkfeed or Samsung's My Magazine implementation?

Tags: android, homescreen

I was recently looking at apps like Blinkfeed and My Magazine that run as fully functional apps but live right next to the Android home screen. Given that widget can only take up a certain amount of space of the home screen and have limited functionality,I could conclude that they aren't widgets.

I would be interested to know how companies like HTC and Samsung implement these full screen apps that live to the left of the screen. I tried googling it but perhaps I am not googling the right thing as I couldn't find a word about how both of these things were implemented. Hence I decided to turn to the wisdom of the internet !! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider homescreen as the Activity that has floating buttons (those that are at the bottom). 
This activity (fragmentactivity to be precise) contains ViewPager of fragments on each page.
And the leftmost page/fragment is the ListView (Blinkfeed).
[image: the activity , (*) are the floating buttons]

(*) are the floating buttons , probably LinearLayout that has transparent background and contains buttons.

[image: the leftmost fragment, listview]